# awk: length() function not working properly

Tags: awk

I am using `match(string,/regex/,array)` or `strip(string,array,/regex/)` in awk and i want to know the lenght of the `array`

Here length() works

```
awk 'BEGIN{a[1]="sometext";print length(a)}'
output: 1
```

Here its not working

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    str="some text simple test";
    match(str,/(test)/,a);
    print "a[1]: "a[1];
    print length(a)
}'
output:
a[1]: test
6
```

Here its strange that it increment the length

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    str="some text simple test";
    match(str,/(test)/,a);
    print "a[1]: "a[1];
    print "a[2]: "a[2];
    print length(a)
}'
output:
a[1]: test
a[2]: 
7
```

why length() is not working and giving wierd output

**Mostly found the reason:**
But not able to undestand even though a[2] does not exist, but its creating a new one. Ideally it should not create a variable if does not exist. Its the commented line

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
        str="some text simple test";
        match(str,/simple (test)/,a);
        print "a[0]: "a[0];
        print "a[1]: "a[1];
        print "a[2]: "a[2]; # a[2] does not exist, but its creating a new one. Ideally it should not create a variable if does not exist
        print "length(a): "length(a)
    k = 0
    for(i in a){
      print "["i"]: "a[i]
      k++
    }
    print "length: "k
    print "RLENGTH::"RLENGTH
    print "RSTART::"RSTART
}'

OUTPUT:
a[0]: simple test
a[1]: test
a[2]: 
length(a): 7
[0start]: 11
[0length]: 11
[1start]: 18
[1length]: 4
[0]: simple test
[1]: test
[2]: 
length: 7
RLENGTH::11
RSTART::11
```

Comment: wrt `even though a[2] does not exist, but its creating a new one. Ideally it should not create a variable if does not exist.` - that's exactly what awk has done with arrays for 40 years so unlikely to change now. If you don't want to create an array entry then test for existence using `i in a` first instead of immediately using `a[i]`.

Comment: also what does `i in a` means

Comment: See the man page, e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Reference-to-Elements

Comment: `for(i=0,i in a, i++){print "["i"]: "a[i]}` this will not print 0start, 0length

Comment: array in awk is like python dictionaries because the index can be a string also not just 0, 1,2 .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, wrt *Here its strange that it increment the length*, it's not strange actually, just referencing `array[subscript]` is **almost** the same as `array[subscript]=""`.

Wrt *why length() is not working and giving wierd output*, it is working though. Gawk manual says:

> `match(s, r [, a])`
>
> ...
>
> If array `a` is provided,  `a`  is
>                                  cleared and then elements `1` through `n` are filled with the portions of `s` that match
>                                  the corresponding parenthesized subexpression in `r`.  The zero'th element of `a` contains  the  portion  of  `s` matched by the entire regular expression `r`.  **Subscripts
>                                  `a[n, "start"]`, and `a[n, "length"]` provide the starting index  in  the  string  and
>                                  length respectively, of each matching substring.**

So, `length` counts `a[0,"start"]`,`a[0,"length"]` etc. as well.

Comment: now i understand. `print array[subscript] then if array[subsript] does not exist then it is the same as array[subscript]=""`.

Comment: Assuming i have a reg exp with multiple brackets like `/(some)(some)/` then first i have to check `if a[0] exists`, then `loop twice the  array a`. How to know anything matched or not

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi no, it's not the same. `array[subscript]=""` sets that value's type to a string (since you specifically initialized it to a null string) while `array[subscript]` sets that type to a numeric-string of value zero-or-null just like any uninitialized scalar variable.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi if match() returns and populates RSTART with 1 or more then you got a match.

Comment: now i understand. `print array[subscript]; checks if array[subsript] does not exist then it creates array[subscript]=zero-or-null of type numeric string`.

Answer (score 4):

awk's [match()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) sets the startindex and endindex for each matched group. As usual, element #0 is set to the whole pattern. So you'll get three items for group 0 (whole string) and group 1 (matched group) contains start, length and values. Check the output of this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{str="some text simple test"; match(str, /(test)/, a); for (i in a) print i":"a[i]}'
0start:18
0length:4
1start:18
1length:4
0:test
1:test
```

Comment: I like @oguzismail answer since it references the manual (first place one should go when they have questions like OP's). I like this answer here because it makes it VERY clear what is going on under the hood using OP's own example. They are different answers for this reason and both compliment each other. Kudos to both of you. I hope you both leave yours up.

Comment: @steffen Indeed you did. Totally missed that. Honestly I was confused on this one too since I don't often monkey with `match()` so it was a pleasure reading both of these and having that itch scratched.